# Change appearance of "zero" symbol in teletype txfonts

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to tweak the teletype fonts of `txfonts` so that the "zero symbol" 0 does not have the rather 1980-style stroke?

[image: Zero]

Perhaps a replacement glyph has been specified by the font? Using `newtxtext` is not an option at the moment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \texttt{0}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of changing the typewriter type font I don't see any way out, as there's no option for changing the 0 to a nonslashed form.

You can revert to the standard CMTT fonts, scaled to be the same height as the `txtt` fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{scmtt}{\hyphenchar\font-1 }
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{scmtt}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    [1.01782] ectt0800
        <9-10>  [1.01782] ectt0900
        <10-12> [1.01782] ectt1000
        <12-17> [1.01782] ectt1200
        <17->   [1.01782] ectt1728
      }{}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{scmtt}{\hyphenchar\font-1 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{scmtt}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    [1.01782] cmtt8
        <9-10>  [1.01782] cmtt9
        <10-12> [1.01782] cmtt10
        <12->   [1.01782] cmtt12
      }{}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{scmtt}

\begin{document}
0\ttfamily 0
\end{document}
```

The scaling factor has been determined by comparing the two fonts.

[image]

Here's a comparison: above the (scaled) CMTT, below the original TXTT font (the first ABCdef012 is in the TX font)

[image]

Comment: What does this mean for the output encoding?

Comment: @user946850 Sorry, I don't get it. I've added definitions both for OT1 and T1 encoding, modelled on the standard ones.

Comment: Well, this might be to my weak understanding of output encoding issues. I see that your code handles an `OT1` and a `T1` case, so I guess everything's fine on that front.