# Scaling cmtt to match times

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling, typewriter

I want to use Times Roman (times) as the default font and Computer Modern Typewriter (cmtt) for monospaced text. However, Computer Modern is a little too large. How do I scale it down document-wide?

If I were using Courier as my monospace font, I could do:

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{couriers}
```

But I cannot find any scaling options for Computer Modern.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70055/4427) can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typeface` package makes scaling pretty easy. By default, it autoscales `\sfdefault`, `\ttdefault` and math to `\rmdefault` ex-height.

Try the little program below, noting that:

- the `cm-super` font set should first be installed (otherwise you'll be loading bitmap computer modern fonts).
- you can see your font metrics using `\tfprint...` commands (enable using `typeface` option `printinfo=true`). This info is usually somewhat wider than a normal page, hence the included `\usepackage[margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}`.
- set `typeface` option `debug=true` to highlight font families in different colors.
- replace option `monotypeface=cm` with `monotypeface=cm:scale:false`, `monotypeface=cm:scale:1.2` or `monotypeface=cm:scale:uppercase` to see what the `scale` suboption can do.

.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% Ensure cm-super fonts are installed or monotypeface=cm option will load
% bitmap (jagged edges, poor scalability) rather than scalable outline fonts
\usepackage[typeface=times,         % as requested
            sanstypeface=helvetica, % for example
            monotypeface=cm,        % as requested
            fontencoding=T1,        % defaults to T1; cf. OT1
            printinfo]{typeface}    % enables \tfprint commands below

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\tfprintinfo
\tfprinttextalphabets

Sample text: ABCDEfghij\texttt{ABCDEfghij}ABCDEfghij

\end{document}
```